# Error in Setting up Azure DevOps Source control with an express web app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to update a express web app and trying to connect VSTS source control to the same but I am getting the following error.

```
 {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 
'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with 
 Microsoft.Web.Hosting.WebHostingException: AADSTS700027: Client 
 assertion contains an invalid signature." }
```

I had an express web app setup with VSTS and it was successfully connected with source control. I haven't changed anything but I am not sure what this error means. I was able to use Azure pipelines but I wasn't able to use "App Service build service" to connect to VSTS. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Are you using Git as source control and having trouble committing your app? Or are you directly linking your Azure web app to source control to automate deployments or... ?

Comment: We are having the exact same error all of the sudden. Though we're using Azure Repos for Continuous Deployment for an Azure App Service.

Comment: We are also using Azure Repos for Continuous Deployment for Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related with an Azure update. They fixed it and the continuous integration via Kudu is working again.